# what is the delegate of these NSURLSession methods in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

XCode is not auto completing this methods i did set the delegate for

`NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`,`NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`

but it still not completing so i feel that i am setting the wrong delegates cause thats what xcode do when i set the wrong delegate

```
URLSession(_:downloadTask:didResumeAtOffset:expectedTotalBytes:)
URLSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)
URLSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:)
```

well whats wrong with swift this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type this into Playground:

```
class Downloader : NSObject, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

}
```

and then start typing inside the class `URLS` you get all the autocompletion stuff. Try that and if this does not work restart Xcode. Maybe "cleaning" the project will also help.

Please also note that the methods you reference in your question are defined by the **`NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate`**, which you did not include.

Sometimes you have to use the up or down arrow key to scroll to the right autocompletion entry.