# Missing argument for parameter 'totalBytesWritten' in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift 3.0.1 and Xcode 8.1.
I am attempting to download a file from the internet programatically.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Somehow this call above is not liked by Xcode. I'm not sure what I am missing.

EDIT:

This is where I'm using this call. Inside of this I get a different error, though.
"Use of instance member 'URLSession' on type 'AdvancedSettingsTableViewController'; did you mean to use a value of type 'AdvancedSettingsTableViewController' instead?"

```
lazy var downloadSession: URLSession = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    return session
}()
```

EDIT 2: It almost seems like it doesn't recognize

```
init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, delegate: URLSessionDelegate?, delegateQueue queue: OperationQueue?)
```

as a valid initializer. If I command click on URLSession I get a question mark.

Comment: Can you show us more code ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571461/download-a-file-with-nsurlsession-in-swift)

Comment: I'm not. The initializer I am trying to call is (init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, 
delegate: URLSessionDelegate?, 
delegateQueue queue: OperationQueue?))

Comment: I added more code in an edit.

Comment: Try, `let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)` I'm not sure you can set the delegate in a getter

Comment: When I try that I get `Missing argument for parameter 'downloadTask' in call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me as well and it seems that it was caused by other problems with the code. After fixing other issues in the file, it stopped complaining.